# Solr: TZ parameter in delete query

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there a way to let Solr properly apply TZ parameter on delete requests? Something like the following curl example doesn't seem to work properly.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/queue-monitor/update?commit=true&TZ=Europe/Paris" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>time:[NOW-1DAY/DAY TO NOW/DAY]</query></delete>'
```

This curl example deletes documents in the range based on UTC instead that applying the TZ.

The same query `q=time:[NOW-1DAY/DAY TO NOW/DAY]` with TZ works properly when selecting.